# SBT. Почему resourceGenerator не добавляет файл, сгенерированный в таске под командой assembly?

Tags: scala, sbt

Я использую SBT 0.13.16

У меня есть таска, которая генерирует файл, путем вызова `main` метода в исходниках. Эта таска вычисляет путь до файла и передает его `main` методу в качестве аргумента.

build.sbt:

```
lazy val myTask = taskKey[Unit]("generates file by executing main method")
myTask := Def.taskDyn {
    val file = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "fileFromTask.txt"
    val path = file.getAbsolutePath

    Def.task {
        (runMain in Compile).toTask(s" com.company.Main $path").value
    }
}.value

assembly := (assembly dependsOn myTask).value

resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
    val file = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "fileFromTask.txt"
    Seq(file)
}.taskValue
```

Main.scala:

```
object Main extends App {
    val path = args(0)

    val file: Path = Paths.get( path )
    Files.createDirectories(file.getParent)
    Files.write(file, "Hi! I am a simple text file".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
}
```

Я не могу понять, почему команда `sbt assembly` генерирует файл(Я вижу его в папке `target\scala-2.12\resource_managed`), но не добавляет его в `jar`?

**НО!**
Если набрать `sbt myTask assembly`, то файл, как и ожидалось изначально, будет добавлен в `jar`. Но ведь это тоже самое(на мой взгляд), что и просто `sbt assembly`. Почему так?

Заметил, что если файл сгенерировать в самой таске, а не в `main` методе, то `sbt assembly` также сможет добавить его в `jar`. Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `sbt myTask assembly` не тоже самое что и `sbt assembly`.

Дело в том что таска `assebmly` сама по себе не смотрит в папку `target\scala-2.12\resource_managed`, за это отвечает другая таска, а `assembly` выполняется после неё. И не смотря на то, что ты поставил `myTask` перед `assembly`, `myTask` всё равно оказывается после той другой таски.

Если набрать в sbt `inspect assembly`, то увидим список других тасок от которых зависит `assebmly` и по окончанию которых начнёт свою работу:

```
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  *:myTask
[info]  *:assembly::packageOptions
[info]  *:assembly::assemblyOption
[info]  *:assembly::streams
[info]  *:assembly::test
[info]  *:assembly::assembledMappings     <--- Смотрим сюда :)
[info]  *:assembly::assemblyOutputPath
```

Т.е. вот эта строчка:

```
assembly := (assembly dependsOn myTask).value
```

гарантирует что `myTask` выполнится раньше `assembly`, но не гарантирует что `myTask` выполнится раньше других таких же зависимостей.

На самом деле - `*:assembly::assembledMappings` тоже не занимается ресурсами, а зависит от другой таски, которая зависит ещё от других и так аж до таски `copyResources`. Эта таска перекладывает ресурсы из папки `target\scala-2.12\resource_managed` в папку `target\scala-2.12\classes`, откуда `assembly` потом забирает.

Кстати, не знаю баг это или фича - если вызовешь `sbt copyResources`, когда папки `target\scala-2.12\resource_managed` нету, а в настройках обещан там файл:

```
resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val file = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "fileFromTask.txt"
  Seq(file)
}.taskValue
```

то sbt, не найдя **файл**, создаст в папке назначения (`target\scala-2.12\classes`) **папку** с таким именем (`fileFromTask.txt`).

Кроме того, наша таска `myTask` тоже зависит от таски `copyResources`, поэтому когда ты вызываешь `myTask` первый раз - он вызывает `copyResources`, который не находит `fileFromTask.txt`, потом вызывается уже сам `myTask` который создаёт `target\scala-2.12\resource_managed\main\fileFromTask.txt`.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. А есть ли способ таки выполнить `myTask` до всего, что вызовет `assembly`?